# Firefox headless never returns from taking screenshot if called from Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, firefox

I play around with firefox taking screenshots in headless mode. I call firefox from a web application in a Tomcat 8 (run on Ubuntu 18.04)  with the following code:

```java
String command = "firefox --headless --screenshot /opt/foobar.png http://foo.bar; pkill firefox";
Process start = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c", command});

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(start.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    log.info(line);
}
int exitCode = start.waitFor();
```

I get the following output (the same as with `getErrorStream()`):
`*** You are running in headless mode.` but afterwards nothing happens. Firefox is not returning and the screenshot is not created.

I know the web application is run by the user `tomcat`, so I created a directory `/var/lib/tomcat8/.cache` with `chmod 777` (for testing only!).

If I call `firefox --headless --screenshot /opt/foobar.png http://foo.bar; pkill firefox` under my user's bash, Firefox creates the screenshot and returns in less than a second.

Any ideas why Firefox is not returning? There seems to be some permission trouble but as Firefox does not output anything it's hard to tell. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to create `/var/lib/tomcat8/.mozilla` and chown it to tomcat8 was well as chmod 77.